# sql, filiter out null columns when using CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case

I'm converting Booleans to text like so:

```
select 
    CASE WHEN admin IS true THEN 'Admin' END,
    CASE WHEN co IS true THEN 'CO' END,
    CASE WHEN corp IS true THEN 'CORP' END, 
    CASE WHEN grind IS true THEN 'grind' END, 
    CASE WHEN vendor IS true THEN 'Vendor' END, 
    CASE WHEN gpm IS true THEN 'GPM' END
from user_profiles where user_name = 'don.smith@happy.com';
```

Unfortunately, this returns null values.  How can I return get back only the fields that have text?

Comment: what sql engine are you using?

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?  Also please tag your question with the appropriate database.

Comment: `How can I return get back only the fields that have text?` Does this mean only return rows where at least one of the fields is true?

Comment: Regardless of the DBMS you're using, you shouldn't END each case, check your syntax.

Comment: @Alfabravo aside from the lack of aliases I don't see a problem with row  result like `{ 'Admin', null, 'CORP', 'grind', null, null}`

Comment: I'm new to sql.  pgsql is my engine.
   @Conrad Frix, you are correct, I just don't want the "null"s.

Comment: Coolios, @MartinSmith, I saw that "Boolean" bit after writing that. I'll dump my comment so it doesn't muck up the convo.

Comment: @Dean yeah it's still not clear to me. If you want empty string instead the `ELSE ''` solutions will do it. If you want to eliminate rows that are *all false* just do [WHERE TRUE in ( "admin", "co", "corp", "grind", "vendor", "gpm")](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9439c/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return this as a single delimited column, then one method is `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 CASE WHEN admin IS true THEN 'Admin' END,
                 CASE WHEN co IS true THEN 'CO' END,
                 CASE WHEN corp IS true THEN 'CORP' END, 
                 CASE WHEN grind IS true THEN 'grind' END, 
                 CASE WHEN vendor IS true THEN 'Vendor' END, 
                 CASE WHEN gpm IS true THEN 'GPM' END
                )
from user_profiles
where user_name = 'don.smith@happy.com';
```

This returns the values as a single column:  a single query cannot have a variable number of columns, so a single column would seem to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make a query to return dinamic number of columns for diferent rows. So if you want remove `NULL` the best you can do is add the `ELSE` clausule to return empty string `''` other wise the default return for the `ELSE` will be `NULL`

And you also should consider include an alias for each field name

```
select 
    CASE WHEN admin IS true THEN 'Admin' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN co IS true THEN 'CO' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN corp IS true THEN 'CORP' ELSE '' END, 
    CASE WHEN grind IS true THEN 'grind' ELSE '' END, 
    CASE WHEN vendor IS true THEN 'Vendor' ELSE '' END, 
    CASE WHEN gpm IS true THEN 'GPM' ELSE '' END
from user_profiles 
where user_name = 'don.smith@happy.com';
```